# Escape struct field in a macro definition

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following structure (simplified):

```
struct error_t{
    const char *file;
    const char *error_desc;
};
```

I wrote a macro to create the structure

```
#define ERROR_SET(error_desc) \
{ \
   struct error_t tmp = {.error_desc = error_desc, .file = __FILE__}; \
   struct error_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)); \
   memcpy(ptr, &tmp, sizeof(tmp)); \
   *error_ptr = ptr; \
}
```

The problem is that at the line

```
struct error_t tmp = {.error_desc = error_desc, .file = __FILE__}
```

both `error_desc`s `.error_desc = error_desc` are replaced which is not what I wanted. The only solution I can see is to rename the macro function parameter from `error_desc` to `_error_desc`, but maybe there is a better way. Maybe we can sort of "escape" the `error_desc` to be substituted in the `.error_desc`?

Comment: Why not go the simple route and simply rename the "argument"?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Agree, but I'm curious if something like this is even possible with `C` preprocessor?

Answer (score 3):

Just do not use the same name for the parameter and the struct member

Answer (score 2):

You can have a different MACRO that the preprocessor would replace as `error_desc`.

```
#define ERROR_DESC error_desc
```

Then you can define `ERROR_SET` like this:

```
#define ERROR_SET(error_desc) \
{ \
   struct error_t tmp = {.ERROR_DESC = error_desc, .file = __FILE__}; \
   struct error_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)); \
   memcpy(ptr, &tmp, sizeof(tmp)); \
   *error_ptr = ptr; \
}
```

This works because the substitution is done only once.

Answer (score 1):

You can "deceive" the preprocessor with something like

```
#define CONCAT(a, b) a##b

#define ERROR_SET(error_desc) \
{ \
   struct error_t tmp = { .CONCAT(error,_desc) = error_desc, .file = __FILE__ }; \
   ...\
}
```

but it is just not worth it. Just rename the parameter. And develop a convention for parameter naming that would help you to avoid such naming conflicts in the future.

---

On the second thought, the extra `CONCAT` macro is not even necessary. This will achieve the same objective

```
#define ERROR_SET(error_desc) \
{ \
   struct error_t tmp = { .error##_desc = error_desc, .file = __FILE__ }; \
   ...\
}
```